# Is it possible to print or save the picturebox with other picture box within it

Tags: vb.net, image, printing, save

I am a vb.net beginner. I got a project that I need to do function that enabled user to add new picture(which is a new picturebox) and move it in a picture box. I have made these two happened but I don`t know how to make the picturebox(that allow new picturebox move inside) save as bitmap/jpg into database. Is that possible to do that.If yes, how?

```
Public Class Form1

    Private btn As Button ' this is a reference object
    Private pic As PictureBox
    Private ptX, ptY As Integer
    Private drag As Boolean


    Private Sub nodepic_MouseDown(ByVal senderPic As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)

        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
            drag = True
            pic = CType(senderPic, PictureBox)
            ptX = e.X : ptY = e.Y
        End If

        If pic.Focused Then
            clearButton.Enabled = True
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub nodepic_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)

        If drag Then
            If pic.Location.X >= 1 AndAlso pic.Location.Y >= 1 AndAlso
                (pic.Location.X + pic.Width) <= panelPictureBox.Width - 5 AndAlso
                (pic.Location.Y + pic.Height) <= panelPictureBox.Height - 5 Then
                pic.Location = New Point(pic.Location.X + e.X - ptX, pic.Location.Y + e.Y - ptY)
                Me.Refresh()
            Else
                drag = False
                pic.Location = New Point(pic.Location.X + e.X - ptX, pic.Location.Y + e.Y - ptY)
            End If
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub node_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
        drag = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub deleteButton(senderPic As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim delete As DialogResult
        delete = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to delete this icon?", "Delete Icon", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
        If delete = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
            senderPic.Dispose()
            locationLabel.Text = String.Empty
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub locationButton(senderPic As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
        pic.Location = New Point(pic.Location.X + e.X - ptX, pic.Location.Y + e.Y - ptY)
        locationLabel.Text = pic.Location.ToString()
    End Sub

    Private Sub TreeView1_AfterSelect(sender As Object, e As TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.NodeMouseDoubleClick

        Dim picBox As New PictureBox

        If e.Node.Name.Equals("red") Then
            picBox.Image = ImageList1.Images(0)
        End If
        If e.Node.Name.Equals("orange") Then
            picBox.Image = ImageList1.Images(1)
        End If
        picBox.Location = New Point(10, 10)
        panelPictureBox.Controls.Add(picBox)
        action(picBox)
    End Sub

    Private Sub action(sender As PictureBox)
        AddHandler sender.MouseDown, AddressOf nodepic_MouseDown
        AddHandler sender.MouseMove, AddressOf nodepic_MouseMove
        AddHandler sender.MouseUp, AddressOf node_MouseUp
        AddHandler sender.MouseDoubleClick, AddressOf deleteButton
        AddHandler sender.MouseClick, AddressOf locationButton
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        panelPictureBox.Enabled = True
        panelPictureBox.BackColor = Color.White
    End Sub

    Private Sub clearButton_Click(senderPic As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles clearButton.Click
        pic.Dispose()
    End Sub**strong text**

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the PictureBox, along with its "child" PictureBoxes, to a Bitmap using code like this:

```
    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(panelPictureBox.Width, panelPictureBox.Height)
    panelPictureBox.DrawToBitmap(bmp, panelPictureBox.ClientRectangle)
```

Next you save it to memory by writing it out to a MemoryStream.  Note that you can specify the format in the second parameter:

```
    Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
    bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

Finally, you can obtain a byte array from the resulting MemoryStream:

```
    Dim bytes() As Byte = ms.ToArray
    ' ... save "bytes" to your database ...
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need to print the image inside the picturebox then you should insert printdialog ,printdocument in side the design of the form then copy the code below

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click

    PrintDialog1 = New PrintDialog

    PrintDialog1.Document = PrintDocument1 'pbxLogo.Image

    Dim r As DialogResult = PrintDialog1.ShowDialog

    If r = DialogResult.OK Then

        PrintDocument1.Print()

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(PictureBox1.Image, 0, 0)

End Sub
```